# Fixed left and right width layout using bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can we create a navbar like below which has `300px` on left side and `300px` on right side with center `100%` width. How we can we achieve this layout using bootstrap navbar.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               |    Center 100% fluid width                       |             
|  SITE LOGO    |------------------------------------------- ----- | Right      +
|               |                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

left fixed width —— middle fluid % —— right fixed width
```

How do we achieve this type of layout navbar using twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put left and right divs inside the center div and After that you need to use `float:left` and `float:right` for left and right divs.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/D2RLR/6364/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-ms-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 centerBox">
        <div class="push-left leftBox">left</div>
        this is center
        <div class="push-right rightBox">right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centerBox {  height:50px; }
.rightBox{ width:100px; height:50px; float:right }
.leftBox{ width:100px; height:50px; float:left }
```

Comment: Thanks Saimak, can you let me know how would i intergate this with bootstrap navbar.

Comment: @theJava You can check out this example: [Navbar](http://www.bootply.com/sp34sOQ9qO)

Comment: Thanks again, but i want your code to be intergrated with navbar where i am facing some difficulties.

Comment: Thanks, How can i ensure my center part is 100% fluid here. I have made changes to your code here. http://www.bootply.com/TBY5Kc1Dt6

Comment: bootply.com/TBY5Kc1Dt6 Is my center 100% fluid width?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply [this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/aItwL) logic

HTML

```
<div class="left">Left</div>
<div class="right">Right</div>
<div class="mid">Mid</div>
```

CSS

```
*{margin: 0}
.left, .right {
  width: 300px;
  background: red
}
.left {
  float: left
}
.right {
  float: right
}
.mid {
  margin: 0 300px;
  background: yellow
}
```